# Merge multiple excel files into R taking only 2nd sheet, retaining file name as 'data source'

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to merge multiple excel files into a single data.frame in R - all files are pulled from a common folder, pulling only the 2nd sheet, which will always have a specific name ('Value Assessment').

In addition be able to retain each file name in a column, so the source of merged data is maintained.

I've been able to load the files and merge into one data.frame, but can't figure out how to retain file name as 'source name'.

```
setwd(/.)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list,read_excel)
df <- rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "id")
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Using `setNames()`:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
file.list <- setNames(file.list, file.list)
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel, sheet = 2)
df.list <- Map(function(df, name) {
  df$source_name <- name
  df
}, df.list, names(df.list))
df <- rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "id")
```

(Note: probably a typo, you were missing `sheet = 2`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Merge All Data from All Excel Files:

```
library(xlsx)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/excel_files")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
data <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 2))

for (i in data.files) {
    data <- rbind(data, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```